# Difference between JLS Example 3.10.5-1. String Literals and Oracle JDK?

Tags: java

### Specification

[Example 3.10.5-1. String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#d5e1634) of the Java Language Specification 8 tells us this:

---

The program consisting of the compilation unit (§7.3):

```
package testPackage;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";
        System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");
        System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");
        System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " ");
        System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo")) + " ");
        System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hel"+lo).intern());
    }
}
class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
```

and the compilation unit:

```
package other;
public class Other { public static String hello = "Hello"; }
```

produces the output:

```
true true true true false true
```

---

### Reality

But the compilation and run with oracle jdk 1.8.0_65 (win) outputs

```
true true true true true true
```

### Question 1

Why is this different?
(I have a guess and will post the answer)

### Question 2

Is this a bug in the specification or the compiler or the interpreter?

If any of this, where to report?

---

### Versions

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac.exe" -version
javac 1.8.0_65
```

Answer (score 4):

### Answer for question 1

The javac compiler does optimization during compile time.

The compiler recognize this as a constant expression:

```
String lo = "lo";
```

and concludes that this must be a constant expression too:

```
"Hel" + lo
```

and therefore assuming the whole term is [interned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) as a string-valued constant expression, we compare an interned string against an equal interned string. Therefore we compare the same references and get `true` and the complete check can be pre-evaluated as true.

### Evidences

1. The byte code (`javap -c`) shows us that we have some precalculations. The expressions from the 1., 4. and 5. print are just replaced with a `"true"`.
2. The following code disarms the optimization:

Source

```
public class StringTest {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";
    String myLo = "";
    if (Math.random() < 10) {
      myLo = "lo";
    }
    System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");
    System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");
    // System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " "); // same package
    System.out.print((hello == ("Hel" + "lo")) + " ");
    System.out.print((hello == ("Hel" + lo)) + " ");
    System.out.print((hello == ("Hel" + myLo)) + " ");
    System.out.println(hello == ("Hel" + lo).intern());
  }
}
```

output:

```
true true true true false true
```

Comment: Even though `JIT` is the smart one, his brother the compiler isn't completely dumb either.